# PL/SQL performance paging cursor (with filtering and fixed result size)

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I have a pl/sql cursor that starts from a defined rowid (given by parameter) for paging queries.

The retrieved rows by the cursor are filtered by special rules - therefore the result rows are not returned immediately but collected in a table type variable.

In a loop I fetch more data from the cursor until 100 "rows" are put to the table type variable. This result is send back from the function.

Everything works properly, but the initial sql query (open cursor) takes very long.
If I limit the rows in the sql statement (comment in the "WHERE rownum <= (100 + p_startfrom)") the query is much faster. But I don't know how much data I have to fetch by looping and filtering.

Is there a way to make the function faster by not adding a fixed "rownum <=" where clause?

```
  function get_metadata(p_toquery in number, p_startfrom in number) return t_Table_metadata
  is
    v_result_tab t_Table_metadata;
    v_return_tab t_Table_metadata := t_Table_metadata();
    
    c_meta SYS_REFCURSOR;
    
    v_size_per_fetch integer := 100;    
  begin
    open c_meta for 
      'SELECT t_type_metadata(....)
      FROM (
        SELECT t.*, rownum r
        FROM (
          select ...
          from   ...
          where  attr1 =  '|| p_toquery||'
          order  by create_date desc
        ) t
      -- with this where-Clause much faster!! WHERE rownum <= (100 + p_startfrom)
      ) f
      WHERE r >= '|| p_startfrom;

    loop
      fetch c_meta bulk collect into v_result_tab limit v_size_per_fetch;

        for i in 1..v_result_tab.count loop

          v_check_row_result := check_row(....);

          if (v_check_row_result = 1 and v_return_tab.count < 100) then
            v_return_tab.extend;
            v_return_tab(v_return_tab.count) := v_result_tab(i);
          end if;

        end loop;

      exit when v_result_tab.count = 0 or v_return_tab.count >= 100;
    end loop;
    close c_meta;
    
    return v_return_tab;
  end;
```

Comment: Using bind variables rather than concatenating literal values in your query will save you the cost of an extra hard parse.  If the problem is the query plan, though, you'd need to show us the query plan that Oracle is using (ideally both with and without the extra predicate).  And the table definitions, available indexes, etc.

Comment: Both sql statements have exactly the same execution plan - if I execute them standalone. The difference occurs by calling the function: if the where-clause is included it takes much longer (1s compared to 0,2s without where-clause) until the data is fetched for the first entry in the loop. Following fetches in the loop are fast. Is it possible to get the execution plan for the function call? That might be difficult I think.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that the execution plan is unchanged when there is an extra predicate.  That would at least show in the predicates section of the plan.  You can interrogate the data dictionary `v$sql`, `v$sql_plan` to see the query plan for the query that is actually built in the function.  In your question, you say that the code is fast if the predicate is included but in your comment you say the code is slow when the predicate is included.  Can you clarify which is fast and which is slow?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Of course the predicate section shows for the "included where clause" query an extra entry. But the rest is equal. The query with the extra predicate is faster, but as stated, only in conjunction with the function. I got no access to v$sql/v$sql_plan. I used SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY) to get the plans for the query executed standalone. Is there another way to get to the plan for the function?

Comment: What are you passing in for `p_startfrom`?  If you want page 3 and are passing 300, you have a bug I think.  If 50 rows were filtered out, page 3 would actually start on row 350.  By starting on 300, you're repeating rows on each page.  Your problems all stem from the fact that you are doing half of the logic in SQL and half in PL/SQL.  Is it possible to move your `check_row()` logic to your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: The client gets the rowid of the result and hands over the last rowid as p_startfrom parameter for the request of the next page. So thats working. I know its a mess to split the logic half in sql and PL/SQL. The PL/SQL filtering is needed due to several access checks. It's impossible to do this by one SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the hint [`FIRST_ROWS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-CEA66568-0168-4AE2-AD3B-FE86CDD73894) to ask Oracle to optimize the query to return a small number of rows quickly. You still have to guess the number of rows that will be needed for the PL/SQL loop, but a ballpark guess, like 1000, will probably work well enough.

```
SELECT /*+ first_rows(1000) */ t_type_metadata(....)
```

As others have commented, it would be ideal if you could put all the conditions into a single SQL statement. With a single SQL statement, adding pagination could be as simple as: `select ... offset 100 rows fetch next 100 rows only;`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try that out and give feedback. Because of the complexity in the check_row() method it is unfortunately not possible to query with a single statement.

Comment: Wow, thats amazing. The hint speeds up the query without extra predition. Now it runs as fast as it is executed standalone. I hope the hint is recognized by oracle in future versions. Without this the first fetch of the loop is too slow. Thanks!